# How to add label (with text) on a sphere in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can make it more clear. I have created a sphere object and a texture is applied onto it from a jpeg image file, as well i have used orbit-controls now i want to add a label with some text at particular position on the sphere the label can be fixed not necessary to move along with the sphere when hovering the mouse.

Comment: Is this link helpful? https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html That seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. yes i have tried this from stemkoski but the thing is i am using a three.js of  "r72" were THREE.SpriteAlignment.topLeft; has been removed. so it is always showing me three.spritealignment.left is undefined...